# How to get input from user at runtime

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, user-input

I want to take runtime input from user in Oracle 10g PL/SQL blocks (i.e. interactive communication with user). Is it possible?

```
declare
x number;
begin
x=&x;
end
```

this code gives error as

> & can't be used in oracle 10g

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To read the user input and store it in a variable, for later use, you can use SQL*Plus command `ACCEPT`.

```
Accept <your variable> <variable type if needed [number|char|date]> prompt 'message'
```

example

```
accept x number prompt 'Please enter something: '
```

And then you can use the `x` variable in a PL/SQL block as follows:

```
declare 
  a number;
begin
  a := &x;
end;
/
```

Working with a string example:

```
accept x char prompt 'Please enter something: '

declare 
  a varchar2(10);
begin
  a := '&x';   -- for a substitution variable of char data type 
end;           -- to be treated as a character string it needs
/              -- to be enclosed with single quotation marks
```

Comment: :sir i have tried this code,it gives following error:               ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: sir is it possible to take input directly, without using SQLPLUS.

Comment: i m running it on oracle 10g database express edition.not on sqlplus

Comment: sqlplus - it's a default oracle database client that can run SQL and PL/SQL commands and display their results. What client do you use?

Comment: yeah sir i m using oracle 10g ,i m running program on GUI based page http://127.0.0.1:8081/apex/f?p=4500:1003:3308902186929148::NO:1003::

Comment: yeah i know sqlplus is tool provided by oracle 10g.but i m running program on GUI based Editor(start-> programs ->Oracle Database 10g Express Edition->Go To Database Home Page)

Comment: Then make your `X` variable a bind variable. For example: a := :x. The window for accepting your data will appear after you press `run`.

Comment: For number datatype, it works perfectly how about few examples for string, varchar,varchar2 datatype.

Comment: @blackjack Example is added.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this too
And it will work:

```
DECLARE
  a NUMBER;
  b NUMBER;
BEGIN
  a := &aa; --this will take input from user
  b := &bb;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('a = '|| a);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('b = '|| b);
END;
```

Comment: Gives `ORA-01008: not all variables bound ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721` error in Oracle Live SQL

Comment: This code doesn't work. It should read a:= &aa; b=&bb; Then SQL will prompt for aa and bb and assign it to a and b.

Answer (score 2):

```
    a number;
    b number;
    begin
    a:= :a;-- instead of "&" use ":" here 
    b:= :b;
    if a>b then
    dbms_output.put_line('Large number is '||a);
    else
    dbms_output.put_line('Large number is '||b);
    end if;

end;
```

Actually when I tried this it worked perfectly and actually "&" is giving error so you can use ":".

hope it you got answer :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have used following line to assign the value which is wrong.

```
x=&x;
```

In PL/SQL assignment is done using following.

**`:=`**

So your code should be like this.

```
    declare
    x number;
    begin
    x:=&x;
-- Below line will output the number you received as an input
    dbms_output.put_line(x);
    end;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
a number;
b number;
begin
a:= :a;
b:= :b;
if a>b then
dbms_output.put_line('Large number is '||a);
else
dbms_output.put_line('Large number is '||b);
end if;
end;
```

Comment: could you explain how does this work? Note the question was posted 5 years ago, has an accepted, well voted answer with few lines, so posting a longer approach after all this time should require some kind of comment on how it is improving the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
`DECLARE
c_id customers.id%type := &c_id;
c_name customers.name%type;
c_add customers.address%type;
c_sal customers.salary%type;
a integer := &a`
```

Here **c_id customers.id%type := &c_id;** statement inputs the c_id with type already defined in the table and statement **a integer := &a** just input integer in variable a.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     a integer;
  3     b integer;
  4  BEGIN
  5     a:=&a;
  6     b:=&b;
  7     dbms_output.put_line('The a value is : ' || a);
  8     dbms_output.put_line('The b value is : ' || b);
  9  END;
 10  /
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to GET and PRINT the prompted value:

```
    set SERVEROUTPUT ON;

   /
     accept v_x number prompt 'Please enter something: '
    declare 
            v_x NUMBER;
    begin
            v_x := &v_x;
            dbms_output.put_line('the entered value was : '  ||  v_x); 
    end;
    
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this in livesql read this .
To my knowledge, this is not possible on livesql. I can't really think of a use case for this, but in any event, you can log feedback in livesql and the team will look at the request.

Answer (score -4):

TRY THIS

```
declare 
  a number;
begin
  a := :a;
dbms_output.put_line('Inputed Number is >> '|| a);
end;
/  

OR

declare 
  a number;
begin
  a := :x;
dbms_output.put_line('Inputed Number is >> '|| a);
end;
/
```

Answer (score -7):

its very simple

just write:

//first create table named test....

```
create table test (name varchar2(10),age number(5));
```

//when you run the above code a table will be created....

//now we have to insert a name & an age..

Make sure age will be inserted via opening a form that seeks our help to enter the value in it

```
insert into test values('Deepak', :age);
```

//now run the above code and you'll get 
"1 row inserted" output...

/now run the select query to see the output

```
select * from test;
```

//that's all
..Now i think no one has any queries left over accepting a user data...

Comment: Please use the code-formatting or the inline code-element to make your posts more readable.