# Oracle PLSQL User input is valid positive number between 0 and 99999

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written the following and am trying to get user input which is a valid positive number and checking whether the student has enrolled in any course, if enrolled it returns the students grades or if the student has not taken any course it returns a statement or it returns stating that the student is not enrolled.

1) I want to know how to check whether user entered valid input number between 0 and 99999 ; and not any negative values or characters.
2) Also I am using the user input in two places, how can I get the user input only once and use it any where else in the program.

create or replace procedure Transcript is

```
s_id takes.id%type;
y takes.year%type;
s takes.semester%type;
d course.dept_name%type;
c course.course_id%type;
t course.title%type;
g takes.grade%type;
c1 course.course_id%type;
s1 takes.id%type;

cursor cu is select year,semester,dept_name,course_id,title,grade 
from course natural join takes where id = &s_id order by year,semester desc;
cursor cu1 is select student.id from student left outer join takes on 
student.id=takes.id where student.id = &s_id and course_id is NULL;
begin
open cu;
open cu1;
fetch cu into y,s,d,c,t,g;
fetch cu1 into s1;
if cu%found 
then
dbms_output.put_line('Year    '||'Semester    '||'Department                '||
'Course ID        '||'Title                       '||'Grade       ');
while cu%found
loop
dbms_output.put_line(rpad(y,10,' ')||' '||rpad(s,10,' ')||' '||rpad(d,20,' ')
||' '||rpad(c,10,' ')||' '||rpad(t,20,' ')||' '||g);
fetch cu into y,s,d,c,t,g;
end loop;
elsif cu%notfound
then
if cu1%found
then
dbms_output.put_line('Student has not taken any courses');
else
dbms_output.put_line('Student is not enrolled');
end if;
end if;
exception
when INVALID_NUMBER then dbms_output.put_line('Enter a valid student id');
when CASE_NOT_FOUND then dbms_output.put_line('Enter a valid input');
end;
```

Comment: You can't prompt for a substitution variable in a procedure, or get any user input. It is executed inside the database, not in the client. Your `&s_id` is evaluated by the client before the procedure is even compiled. If you look at the stored procedure code it will have the value you entered then, and will always have that same value. Your procedure should have an argument for the value; if you really want to use PL/SQL for this at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.So, you mean to say I need to send the s_id as an argument to procedure.Then, use "exec procedure (1234)" to run the code.So how to check for invalid number in the argument of the procedure?I mean how to check if its not a character/string/negative number

Comment: If the formal argument declaration is `number` then it will throws ORA-01722 if you pass a string that can't be implicitly converted to a number. You would have to check the number is in your desired range inside your procedure though, and throw an exception or show a message depending on what you want to happen. Are you required to do this in a procedure, and use dbms_output, which is not good practice as the client may not have it enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: 
 
To check if a value is between the 0 and 99999 you can use an if statement, and if it doesn't match raise an error or something.

```
nId NUMBER := 701;
IF nId < 0 OR nId > 99999 THEN 
    -- nId not between the 0 and 99999. 
END IF;
```

Question 2: 
PL/SQL is used for databases, so normaly you don't ask the user directy for input. 
 
But to answer you question. You can store it in a variable like `nId` in the example above. Or save it in a temporary table, then delete variables after use.

[Maybe this link will also get you an idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516930/how-to-get-input-from-user-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: 
You may use **no_data_found** exception to determine whether the user entered valid student id, with this approach you can control the valid input from Exception Block Itself.

Question 2: 
You can use the temporary variable to store the input to use it repetitively.