# i want to accept user input in PL SQL and pass it to procedure, show me a simple program for it?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i want accept user input and pass it to procedure, accept prompt should execute only when i enter
**' / '**

```
        Create OR Replace Procedure  input(Roll IN number, Book_n IN varchar)
        AS
        <--procedure body-->
        end;
        /

        Declare
        Roll_no  number;
        B_name varchar(20);
        Begin 
        Accept Rollno number prompt 'Enter Roll number : ';
        Accept BookName varchar(20) prompt 'Enter book name : ';

        input(Rollno,BookName);
        end; 
        /
```

Comment: A simple google will give you many result. For example this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516930/how-to-get-input-from-user-at-runtime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get input from user at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516930/how-to-get-input-from-user-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&inp_variable` to pass external input  to PL/SQL variable.`ACCEPT` is not PL/SQL keyword. use it externally.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
ACCEPT Rollno NUMBER PROMPT 'Enter Roll number : ';
ACCEPT BookName varchar(20) prompt 'Enter book name : ';

DECLARE
   Roll_no   NUMBER := &Rollno;
   B_name    VARCHAR (20) := '&BookName';
BEGIN
   input (Roll_no, B_name);
END;
/
```

> accept prompt should execute only when I enter ' / '

It is not a proper way to run your code like this. use other checks inside proc to control the user input.

Answer (score 0):

try the below to accept input when executing a pl\sql block.

> you can use '/', if you already executed the pl\sql block or write
>   block using 'sql>**ed**'
>
> use '&' followed by a name to accept input from user. i.e. **&Roll_No**

```
Declare
  Roll_no  number;
  B_name varchar(20);
Begin 
  --Accept Rollno number prompt 'Enter Roll number : ';
  Roll_no := &Roll_no;
  --Accept BookName varchar(20) prompt 'Enter book name : ';
  B_name := '&Book_Name';
  input(Roll_no,B_name);
end; 
/
```

this will prompt for input ..

- Enter value for Roll_no:
- Enter value for Book_Name:

Answer (score 0):

Create OR Replace Procedure  input(Roll IN number, Book_n IN varchar)
        AS
        <--procedure body-->
        end;
        /
Accept Rollno number prompt 'Enter Roll number : ';
Accept BookName varchar(20) prompt 'Enter book name : ';

```
    Declare
    Roll_no  number;
    B_name varchar(20);
    Begin

    Roll_no:= &Rollno;
    B_name := '&BookName'

    input(Roll_no,B_name);
    end; 
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

set serveroutput on;

Accept Roll_no number prompt 'Enter Roll number : ';
Accept B_name varchar2 prompt 'Enter book name : ';

```
Declare
    Roll_no  number:= NULL;
    B_name varchar2(20):= NULL;

    Begin

    Roll_no:= &Roll_no;
    B_name:= '&B_name';

    input(Roll_no,B_name);

    end; 
    /
```