# How to prompt for user input on PLSQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm having trouble getting user input inside of a PLSQL procedure. Everywhere I have looked I've come to the conclusion that is not possible or a PLSQL procedure it not made for user input.

### My code:

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE LAB5 AS
daysShow NUMBER;
PROCEDURE show_bizdays2(p_startDate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, p_bizDayShow NUMBER);

PROCEDURE show_bizdays2(p_startDate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE);

FUNCTION Get_Descr(f_sectionId NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2;

END LAB5;
```

### Description:

In this code the first procedure accepts two parameters **a date** and **the amount of business days** to show preceding that date. Works fine.

The second procedure overloads the first and is supposed to be exactly the same however it takes **one** parameter and prompts for the user input in the procedure. Or as described in my notes "ONE input parameter - Start Date and will prompt user to enter how many days are needed to show."

### My Question(s)

Can you prompt for user input inside of a procedure?

Can I somehow use a global variable in the package that prompts the user when the overloaded procedure is called?

Comment: You can't prompt for user input inside of a procedure. The way to interact with users is to write an application (or use an existing one) that interacts with users (which is NOT an SQL or PL/SQL piece of software), and to call the PL/SQL procedure from that application, passing the user inputs to the procedure.

Comment: @mathguy: please make this an answer. All the related questions I checked said "Use the ACCEPT command in SQL*PLUS to get the data, then pass it to the PL/SQL procedure", but that is really answering the wrong question. Your comment is correct: there's no way to get user input directly in PL/SQL. And respond to this comment, if you would, so I can upvote. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis - The reason I posted it as a Comment and not as an Answer is that ... I was simply confirming the (correct!) answer the OP found himself already.

Comment: @mathguy Seems like that is the right answer.  I have no idea why my prof is asking this (since procedures can't take user input) so I'll have to ask him in class...thanks for the help. If you make an answer I'll mark correct :)

Comment: In that case he may not be distinguishing between PL/SQL and SQL\*Plus, and may be thinking that using the `ACCEPT` command in SQL\*Plus is the same as "getting user input in PL/SQL", [in which case you might refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135021/i-want-to-accept-user-input-in-pl-sql-and-pass-it-to-procedure-show-me-a-simple). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to sql you can use & operater for getting input from user.

Example :

```
Declare 
Table_nm:='&tblnm'; 
Begin
Execute immediate ('drop table '¦¦' '¦¦table_nm¦¦' '¦¦' purge') ;
End;
```