# How to code for getting user input in PLSQL?

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I'm writing the following code in plsql for a user input but I don't know why its not working. I'll be thankful for a needed help in correcting it.

```
declare 
   -- Local variables here
   i number(10);
   id number(4);
begin
   i := 8||dbms_random.value(10000,99999);
   i := i * 10000 + &id;
   dbms_output.put_line(i);
end;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Does this answer your question? [How to get input from user at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516930/how-to-get-input-from-user-at-runtime)

Comment: Which window type are you using? If it's a Test Window, inputs go in the variable section at the bottom of the screen, but it won't pop up an interactive prompt if that's what you are asking. For that you need a SQL Window with variable substitution enabled as in @JohnHeller's answer. You can do a lot more with these, such as prompting with a list of valid values from a query.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure variable substitution is enabled in PL/SQL Developer, check for a blue ampersand button in the bottom left hand corner of the main window. When you hover the mouse cursor over the button, the pop up text "Variable substitution enabled" should display.

If the ampersand button is red, then variable substitution is disabled, and you can simply click the button to enable it.

[image]